# In a Helm prompt, how do I copy a candidate for editing?

Tags: helm

Sometimes, I want to make a new file that's named similarly to an existing file. For example, I might want to copy a file to a second filename (`foo.txt.backup`), or move it to the right place (`pretty-long-file-name.hmtl`).

In these cases, I often want to take a candidate and modify it somehow, before selecting it. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to copy/rename the selected file, you can do <kbd>M-C</kbd>/<kbd>M-R</kbd> respectively. If you want to yank just the selection into helm, you can use <kbd>C-c C-y</kbd>, or <kbd>C-u C-c C-y</kbd> if you want to yank the whole path for editing.

(<kbd>C-h b</kbd> in helm will give you a list of all the available bindings.)